# Angular 10, dynamic origin Url for different api

Tags: angular

I have a requirement where my API calls maybe done to different API servers(it will be decided on auth api, stored in session storage). So the calls may be sometimes to `https://domain1.com, https://domain2.com, https://domain3.com.`

Currently I am using `enviornment.origin`  to set the apiPath. But I cant set this dynamically on the go. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: http interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

If your API domains are changed dynamically, one option can be to use a `config.json` file. Config file will be fetched during bootstrap of your app.

Your `config.json` can look like this:

```
{
    origin: 'https://domain2.com'
}
```

You can use e.g. [@ngx-config/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-config/core) to load the config.json to let your app know what is the current API domain. @ngx-config/core uses [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) token and will ensure your app has necessary data on startup.

This way you don't have to build in API domain to you application, but it can be changed dynamically.

Comment: would that would mean I will have to keep my api domains in config.json? But I am unaware of those domains beforehand, it would be passed to by auth services along with other dynamic configs like theme/access-rights etc.

Comment: yes, this means you would need to keep your domains in the config.json.

Comment: If the API domains are passed to your app as a response from auth service, then you need to store the domain from the response e.g. in a service. Then for every backend call you would fetch the value to construct correct API endpoint. You can do this in two ways 1. in the interceptor or 2. by creating another service, that will wrap HttpClient and will construct endpoint URL before passing it to the HttpClient. Let me know, if this is helpful, I can update the answer.